# Cannot find directory location of cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to pass data to a .bat file using cookie data from my HTML/JavaScript page.  The cookie is being created, which I can verify the data being pulled back to the HTML page.  However, when I go to visually look at the cookie as a txt file, it does not exist in the directory designated by my browser.  I need to know it's path so the .bat can know where to look, as well as read its formatting.

```
function getjobnumber(){
    /*job_absolute represents a text field in the HTML*/
    /*the use of the £ sign is to help the .bat file find the right data*/

    var jobnumber =  document.getElementById("job_absolute").value;
    document.cookie = "job_number£=" +jobnumber; "£; expires=Sat, 31 Dec 2050 12:00:00 UTC; path=/"; 
    }
```

When I go to the directory that my browser specifies there is no cookie file there.  The odd thing is that I had this working at one point on one machine, and was able to directly access the cookie file.  When I moved the code to a different machine it did not work.

Comment: Why do you have `£` characters in your cookie?

Comment: What OS and browser are you using? Where are you looking for the cookie file?

Comment: The £ are for when the bat file reads it to truncate the text.  Im using ie11, looking waaaay deep in the C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files

Comment: I don't think that's the correct place. See https://www.thewindowsclub.com/cookies-folder-location-windows

Comment: I tried the locations listed on that document, and the batch file cannot locate the cookies within.